# How might I read a text file in C and print it to the screen?

Tags: c, scanf, readfile

I have a text file that contains data that contains key-value pairs

```
(Ann, 67) (Jhon, 78) (Mason, 89)
(Simon, 34) (Ruko, 23)
```

Each item is separated by space and there is a space after comma

I want to read each element and print those items one by one

```
(Ann, 67)
(Jhon, 78)
(Mason, 89)
(Simon, 34)
(Ruko, 23)
```

I tried using the following code:

```
    while (fscanf(file, "%s", value) == 1) {
        printf(value);
    }
```

but have not succeded - the code separated each value with a comma giving me the following output:

```
(Ann,
67)
(Jhon,
78)
(Mason,
89)
```

How can I do that?

Comment: The [`scanf` family of functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) can do simple pattern matching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, the [`scanf` family of functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) have simple pattern matching which could be used to read your input:

```
char text[32];
int value;

while (fscanf(file, " (%32[^,], %d)", text, &value) == 2)
{
    printf("Got (%s, %d)\n", text, value);
}
```

Explanation of the `scanf` format used:

- `" "` matches any leading white-space
- `"("` matches the opening parenthesis
- `"%32[^,]"` matches (at most 32) characters *except* the comma
- `","` matches the comma
- `"%d"` matches the integer value
- `")"` matches the closing parenthesis

Comment: Thanks Mate works well, If I want to check errors   like (@Tye,45) or (Ann,James) How Can do that? Do I need to extract whole string and check  characters or any other way ?

Comment: @SAGA It's not clear in your question, but if each pair is on its own line, then use e.g. `fgets` (or `getline` if you have that) to read the whole line. Then use `sscanf` instead. If the reading of the line succeed and `sscanf` returns `2` then the input is valid.

Comment: @ Some programmer dude: I am just wondering what exactly is %32[^,]?

Answer (score 1):

When you make the data file you can use commas. This is an example of what that would look like:

**Code**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    FILE *inFile;
    char name[20], str[80], *i;
    int age;

    inFile = fopen("test.txt", "r");
    if (inFile == NULL){
        printf("Error opening file");
        exit(1);
    }

    while(fgets(str, 80,inFile) != NULL){
        i = strtok(str, ", ");
        strcpy(name, i);
        puts(name);

        i = strtok(NULL, ", ");
        age = atoi(i);
        printf("%d\n", age);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Text File**

```
Ann, 67
Jhon, 78
Mason, 89
Simon, 34
Ruko, 23
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

```
while(fscanf...)
```

You may try something like :

```
while ((line=getline(&line, &len, file)) != -1) {
    printf("%s", line);
}
```